# Baking Normals in blender - Normal map completely blue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I've seen this problem many times, but I still can't find a solution to it.
When I bake the two objects, the normal map is completely blue.
Here are my steps:

0. Select both meshes and click alt+g to clear the location
1. Click the Normal node in the node editor
2. Click the high-poly mesh (without the UV map)
3. Shift click low-poly mesh (with the UV map)
4. In the render-Bake settings, set bake type to normal, check selected to active and set the ray distance to 0.1
5. Click Bake

Screen capture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rc5plmrgHKqXaKSYGr9aAUrA_SkWHHIX/view
Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5BUs2dgk0lVyjhgKR0NsDqW18e0nSV6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your low poly has 2 materials, so I guess you need to also create an *Image Texture* node in the other material with the same *Normal* image loaded. Or simply delete Material.001 and bake.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.